# Power Bi Report with dynamic field to capture user values

Tags: powerbi

Here is my use case:
I have a power bi dashboard and the data source is an excel file that resides in sharepoint site.
I need to add 2 more columns called “comments” and “eta” in the power bi report and users should be able to add values to “comments” and “eta” and it should reflect in the power bi report.

Answer (score 0):

Modify this video explanation according to your requirement

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzAAR6TBpDc
```